# IterableMapping showing while deploying main contract

Tags: remix, bsc

I wanted to test out this contract from BSC

https://bscscan.com/address/0xc53dbb909a5077b180093b4603d5535bf7bf97e0#code

upon copying it on remix, a prompt with "test.sol:IterableMapping pending.." is showing and upon deploying it on testnet the library IterableMapping is deployed instead of the main contract

anyone having the same issue in the past?

Answer (score 0):

In Remix, in the Deploy & Run transaction there's a dropdown that allow to select the contract to deploy.

By default the existing contracts are sorted alfabetically. I think you have to select the `DaddyDollar` contract.